# Https connection time out since installing PPTP

Tags: apache, ubuntu, timeout, pptp

I have absolutely no doubt that this is human error due to the fact I have no real clue what I am doing.

I recently installed pptp on my ubuntu 12.04 server so that I can vpn as the server.

However I have obviously open/closed the wrong ports.

Apache starts perfectly as you would expect.

I followed these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server/305401), point being. I believe my 443 port is closed or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Silly really wasn't it.

Port was closed as I suspected:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```